# Font going outside of the div in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

Okay so In chrome my font looks great, as you can see here - https://gyazo.com/9265ad0ebad485e458aa3195ec40e32e

And here is the code for it -

```
.logo-div {
    width: 168px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.logoH2 {
    font-family: FiraLight;
    font-size: 23px;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    color: yellow;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

-

But this is how it looks in IE - https://gyazo.com/5c745e71691d0f024c9a1f60fc459d6e]

And I found out that its maybe the fonts fault, because when I uncheck the font-family box in IE it centers it fine, as you can see here - https://gyazo.com/8f7050fb229020c7fb4f3d22a6fa869b

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8f7050fb229020c7fb4f3d22a6fa869b That is the last link

Comment: meni isto izgleda samo sto je drugi font ne kapiram

Comment: Can you edit your question to update the link rather? Better to provide an example of the actual issue in question. Even better to provide a live link so that the issue can be replicated, or at least post the bare minimal working code required in a snippet embedded into your question in order to accurately reproduce the issue. Also, what have you already tried, other than changing the font family? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried couple of different things on this site, but it doesn't seem to work...